# Flash Bug - Force screen repaint

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, repaint

I have a Flash project that is a little unique in that it's an AS3 project that loads AS2 SWF files.

I used the JumpEye bridge to make it all play together, but I'm experiencing a weird bug.

The bridge file has two locations to load a SWF file.  The main section and the preview section.

The first time I load a preview, it loads and closes fine, but the second time I try, the loaded SWF files backgroud disappears, but the elements remain on the screen.

I've tried just about every hack I can think of, but I'm running out of ideas.  I'm thinking that maybe I need to tell Flash to repaint everything, but I can't seem to find the command.

Also, and suggestions that might work to close the preview movie other than:

```
    preview.removeMovieClip();
    preview._visible = false;       
    preview._alpha = 0;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does the AS2 movie actually contain? Is there any code in it or is it just visual stuff?

There isn't any way to completely kill off a loaded SWF. If it registers event handlers or intervals then they could keep running. It's possible those are interfering with the movie when it's loaded the second time.

Comment: Most of the time it's just a boring old SWF getting loaded.  There are some that are interactive, but the behavior is the same no matter which SWF is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to repaint in flash, as the whole stage is repainted every frame. And though there's no way to manually force a loaded SWF out of memory, once you call removeMovieClip on it, it's out of the display tree for good.

Of course it's possible you have a Flash bug, but it's far more likely to be a content problem. Can you expand on what you mean by "the loaded SWF files backgroud disappears"? Do you mean the solid background color of the SWF, or do you mean elements of the SWF's contents that just happen to be in back of other elements? And what JumpEye component are you using?

Comment: The background of the loaded SWF disappears, but the elements on the SWF remain visible.

The JumpEye component I'm using is the ActionScript bridge:

http://www.jumpeyecomponents.com/Flash-Components/Various/ActionScript-Bridge-91/

Comment: The background color of a SWF is not normally displayed when it's loaded into another movie, only when it is the base movie of that instance of the flash player. If you're seeing the backgrounds displayed the first time, that's probably because the component is doing it for you, and failing to do it the second for some reason. Either way though, there is no way (or need) to tell Flash to repaint the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested:

At this point, it's looking like a known bug in Flash:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/194/tn_19435.html

Instead of using removeMovieClip, I used unloadMove and that seems to be doing the trick.  I still have some more testing to do, but this appears to be the solution.